# Forces between current carrying wires

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electricity, experimental-physics, electric-current

Why the wires bearing current in the same direction don't attract to each other?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 3):

They **do** attract each other. The electric field around a current carrying wire(conductor) is given by the right hand grip rule.The thumb points upwards and is the direction of current, while the fingers curl up in the direction of magnetic field. Thus, both wires have same circular magnetic field around them. The direction of field lines will be same because direction of current is same in both wires.For circular magnetic field lines there is no north or south pole.If the two circular field lines have same direction(both are clockwise or anticlockwise) then the current carrying wires always attract each other.This is because the theory suggests that the 2 circular fields interact to produce one singular bigger circular field with same direction.Thus the current carrying wires tend to adhere together to resemble a higher magnitude current producing that bigger circular field.

Comment: But the wires carrying current to our houses donot do so .why?

Comment: @Sohit They do, but the force is too small. Typically, such large wire networks are trying to use the least possible current with the highest possible voltage. It is because losses are related mainly with the current. And also the magnetic field strength is proportional with the current, and not the voltage. There isn't too much current in such a cable (btw, the maximal current in a wire has strong physical constraints).

Comment: @Sohit The magnetic effects of a single wire are mainly very low, the high magnetic fields (like in electromagnets) are reached with using a lot of wires in the same direction.